# MLCP ingestion of multi character "~|^" delimitted file into Marklogic

Tags: nosql, marklogic, delimiter, mlcp, data-ingestion

I have a delimited text file with delimiter as **`~|^`**.
I need to ingest this file into marklogic using MLCP. For this I tried MLCP ingestion using 2 ways.

1. Using MLCP without options file

   `mlcp.sh import -username admin -password admin -input_file_type delimited_text -delimiter "~|^" -document_type json -host localhost -database test -port 8052 -output_uri_prefix /test/data/ -generate_uri -output_uri_suffix .json \-output_collections "Test" -input_file_path inputfile1.csv`
2. Using MLCP with options file

   `mlcp.sh import -username admin -password admin -options_file delim.opt -document_type json -host localhost -database test -port 8052 -output_uri_prefix /test/data/ -generate_uri -output_uri_suffix .json \-output_collections "Test" -input_file_path inputfile1.csv`

My options file looks like this (delim.opt):

```
-input_file_type
delimited_text
-delimiter
"~|^"
```

But in both the ways, mlcp didnt work and I got the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid delimiter: ~|^

Can anyone please help me with how I can ingest these types of CSV files through MLCP into MarkLogic?

Answer (score 2):

I believe MarkLogic content pump cannot support parsing multi-character delimiters. [MarkLogic content pump](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump/blob/2df45ad85eaec3ac91ff7f68835b7e78b0adf176/mlcp/src/main/java/com/marklogic/contentpump/DelimitedTextReader.java) uses the [Apache Commons CSV library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) to parse delimited text. As of today, it looks like there is an open issue with parsing delimited text for multi-character delimiters, see issue [CSV-206](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CSV-206).

For now you could create new delimited text files with single character delimiters. I often use `sed` in the command line to replace strings in files. If you go this route be aware that you'll need to escape any occurrences of the new delimiter in the record values.